# How to use JNI in Delphi 7

Tags: java, delphi, java-native-interface, delphi-7

I need to load a java application to a delphi project. The jre ,j3d and jdk are present in a folder named java_files within the delphi application folder. Java class also present in the same folder. I need to load this class into delphi application. How can I done this

Comment: can you clarify your requirement. You have a java class that you want to export into your delphi program? Is that correct?

Comment: Sorry I didn't know that. Now I accepted the answer which is most useful to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A websearch for *JNI delphi invocation* turned up this as the first hit: [Using the Java Native Interface with Delphi](http://www.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/). It appears to be exactly what you are looking for.  The part that is relevant to your needs is [Introduction and Tutorial: Part Three - The Invocation API](http://www.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/JEDI/DOCS/delphi-jni-3.html)

Comment: +1 for mentioning [Using the Java Native Interface with Delphi](http://www.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/) :-)

Comment: @Nelson Could you please move the tick back to the answer of @splash. It was there first and my answer is essentially identical. I can't delete my answer until it's no longer the accepted answer.

Answer (score 6):

This is typically the first address for JNI integration in Delphi: [Using the Java Native Interface with Delphi](http://home.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/). As I understand your question you want to use the [*Invocation API*](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/invocation.html) part of the JNI.

Comment: I've only just come to my senses and finally understood your comments. I'm not quite sure how I managed to produce an answer identical to yours. I do apologise. It does look pretty bad though! And now it seems that OP has moved the accept tick from your answer to mine. I'm doubly sorry about that. If OP would move the tick back to your answer I will delete mine. I've given you a few upvotes on other questions to (hopefully) compensate for my cheek.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Thanks for the kind apology and for the upvotes (you brought me to 5k :-D)! I did't resent you for your identical answer. That's just what happens. Sorry for my somewhat ironic comment, but I _really_ find it funny to comment to your answer. ;-)

Comment: I can't apologise enough. I didn't do it on purpose and only hope that you accept that.

Answer (score 2):

I did a [talk](http://entwickler-konferenz.de/konferenzen/ekon11/sessions.php?tid=590#session-8) on JNI integration from Java in Delphi (calling Java from Delphi) at the German [EKON 11](http://entwickler-konferenz.de/konferenzen/ekon11) conference in 2007. The handouts are [here](http://jp.home.xs4all.nl/blog-dl/2007/Talking-Java-From-Delphi.pdf) in English.

Of course it mentions the [Pacifier page on JNI with Delphi](http://www.pacifier.com/~mmead/jni/delphi/) that the others mentioned as well.

If you need the demo sources, let me know and I'll dig in my archive for you.

Answer (score 1):

I have to say I'm biased in my answer, being the author of the product, but have you had a look at [Java for Delphi](http://www.j4soft.com/products/java-for-Delphi/)?

It's a Delphi Java integration product that offers all the benefits of JNI (inprocess integration) but without it's inconveniences, among others much shorter code and it's type safe.

For example:

```
var AJavaString: Ijava_lang_String;
begin
   ...
   AJavaString := Tjava_lang_String.Create('A Delphi string going to Java');
   Memo1.Lines.Add(AJavaString.ToString); // And coming back to Delphi
   ...
end;
```